# Возможно ли модифицировать письмо в mta postfix?

Tags: python, postfix

Добрый день, есть сервер postfix, необходимо на нем модифицировать входящие письма и передавать пользователю, например удалять вложенные файлы и прикрепить другой файл. Возможно ли подобное сделать?, Например используя python.

Comment: Отправители зашифрованных писем обидятся

Comment: Согласно документации http://www.postfix.org/local.8.html для локальной доставки может быть использован внешний скрипт. копайте в этом направлении. У меня к sendmail например по такому же принципу прикручен мой собственный деливери агент сделанный на перле, который в т.ч. проверяет письма спамассасином, антивирусом, потом сам раскладывает на диск в нужные мне папки майлбоксов. И добавляет свои заголовки. т.к. на этом этапе ему доступен полный текст письма на стандартном вводе, он может делать с письмом все что угодно